Modify an LFU Cache in Python
I would like to implement an LFU cache this way:

whenever an element is evicted from the cache, I would like to store its key and frequency in a dict named __del_freq in my code.
if a new item need to be set in the cache then first it should be found in the dict __del_freq. If it is there, then the __counter should be set equal to the frquency stored in __del_freq. Finally, this new item needs to be deleted from the dict __del_freq.

I created a subclass of LFUCache that aims to complete all above. Unfortunately, my code does not do what it is supposed to do, e.g. the newly set item never deleted from the dict __del_freq.

Can you add your code?

There are several ways to do this.

You can create your own LFU Cache class using Doubly Linked List.
This way you can customize it as much as you want.
Flexibility is high.
You would add self.__del_freq = {} to your class and consequently change the related methods.

from collections import defaultdict


class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, val):
        self.key, self.val = key, val
        self.prev = self.next = None
        self.freq = 1


class DLL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sentinel = Node(None, None)
        self.sentinel.next = self.sentinel.prev = self.sentinel
        self.size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def append(self, node):
        node.next, node.prev = self.sentinel.next, self.sentinel
        node.next.prev = node
        self.sentinel.next = node
        self.size += 1

    def popitem(self, node=None):
        if self.size == 0:
            return
        if not node:
            node = self.sentinel.prev
        node.prev.next = node.next
        node.next.prev = node.prev
        self.size -= 1
        return node


class LFU:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.size, self.capacity = 0, capacity
        self.node = {}
        self.freq = defaultdict(DLL)
        self.minf = 0
        self.hit_count = 0
        self.miss_count = 0
        self.__del_freq = {}

    def __update(self, node):
        f = node.freq
        self.freq[f].popitem(node)
        if self.minf == f and not self.freq[f]:
            self.minf += 1
        node.freq += 1
        f = node.freq
        self.freq[f].append(node)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.node:
            self.miss_count += 1
            return "MISS"
        self.hit_count += 1
        node = self.node[key]
        self.__update(node)
        return node.val

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if self.capacity == 0:
            return

        if key in self.node:
            self.hit_count += 1
            node = self.node[key]
            self.__update(node)
            node.val = val
        else:
            self.miss_count += 1
            if self.size == self.capacity:
                node = self.freq[self.minf].popitem()
                del self.node[node.key]
                self.__del_freq[node.key] = node.freq
                self.size -= 1

            node = Node(key, val)
            if key in self.__del_freq:
                node.freq = self.__del_freq[key]
                del self.__del_freq[key]
            self.node[key] = node
            self.freq[node.freq].append(node)
            self.minf = node.freq
            self.size += 1


cache = LFU(3)
cache.__setitem__("apple", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'true'}")
cache.__setitem__("orange", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'true'}")
cache.__setitem__("cherry", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'false'}")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
cache.__getitem__("cherry")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
cache.__getitem__("cherry")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
cache.__getitem__("cherry")
print(f"HIT count: {cache.hit_count}")
print(f"MISS count: {cache.miss_count}")
cache.__setitem__("banana", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'false'}")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
print(f"HIT count: {cache.hit_count}")
print(f"MISS count: {cache.miss_count}")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
print(f"HIT count: {cache.hit_count}")
print(f"MISS count: {cache.miss_count}")


cachetools

You can alternatively inherit from cachetools import LFUCache:
You can make the changes, as you require.
In this scenario, you can define a new class, LFU, within which, you would add the following in the __init__:

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.cache = LFUCache(maxsize=capacity)
        self.__del_freq = defaultdict(int)

and accordingly we write our methods:
from collections import defaultdict
from cachetools import LFUCache


class LFU:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.cache = LFUCache(maxsize=capacity)
        self.hit_count = 0
        self.miss_count = 0
        self.__del_freq = defaultdict(int)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.cache:
            self.miss_count += 1
            return "MISS"
        self.hit_count += 1
        return self.cache[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if self.cache.maxsize == 0:
            return

        if key in self.cache:
            self.hit_count += 1
        else:
            self.miss_count += 1
            if len(self.cache) == self.cache.maxsize:
                evicted_key, _ = self.cache.popitem()
                self.__del_freq[evicted_key] += 1

        self.cache[key] = val

    def popitem(self):
        return self.cache.popitem()


cache = LFU(3)
cache.__setitem__("apple", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'true'}")
cache.__setitem__("orange", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'true'}")
cache.__setitem__("cherry", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'false'}")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
cache.__getitem__("cherry")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
cache.__getitem__("cherry")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
cache.__getitem__("cherry")
print(f"HIT count: {cache.hit_count}")
print(f"MISS count: {cache.miss_count}")
cache.__setitem__("banana", "{'type':'fruit', 'available': 'false'}")
cache.__getitem__("banana")
print(f"HIT count: {cache.hit_count}")
print(f"MISS count: {cache.miss_count}")
cache.__getitem__("apple")
print(f"HIT count: {cache.hit_count}")
print(f"MISS count: {cache.miss_count}")


print(cache._LFU__del_freq)


Prints
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'orange': 1})
